# What is the Design Sprints methodology?

Tags: methodology

I have started to notice people talking about this new fast method of coming up with a product/UX design called "Design Sprint".
Can anyone elaborate on what it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be referring to Google Venture's "Design Sprint" process: http://www.gv.com/lib/the-product-design-sprint-a-five-day-recipe-for-startups.

They've basically created a highly condensed, 5-day "sprint" where they help clients:

1. Understand a design problem
2. Develop as many potential solutions as possible
3. Pick the best solutions and start creating user stories
4. Rapidly develop a prototype
5. Conduct rapid usability testing on that prototype

From what I can tell there's nothing here that's out of the ordinary except that they are condensing quite a bit of work into 5 intense days.  They are still basically going through the industry standard user centered design process - researching the problem, developing with users in mind, and evaluating via usability tests.

Comment: We used to call this 'war rooming' or 'whiteboarding' :)